# Load in content to div without javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wounder if there is any way to load in content from a external page (page in same website/root) to a div wihout using javascript?

The site use alot of jquery load() but it have a page that must be available wihout having javascript activated. It should fit the website structure much better to load in that content insteed of reload the whole page, so now I looking for some solution without javascript if that exist.

Example: the div I want to load content to is `Index.html` `#get_content` and the page and div that contains the content is `Content.html` `#send_content`.

Thanks.

Comment: No JavaScript is an odd limitation nowadays. What kind of client is it? Are there other limitations we should know?

Comment: @Potatoswatter It's not an odd limitation, NoScript is the 6th most popular add-on for JS https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/extensions/?sort=users If you are building a public facing website, you'll lose lots of users if you require JS. NoScript users only enable JS for sites they trust, and you have to earn their trust first. By the way, I do not develop public facing sites, I write entirely JS based web applications.

Comment: I meant add-on for firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery load() is the best way to accomplish this on the server-side.

You could use an [iFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe), like this:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/something.html"></iframe>
```

There's a lot of properties which can be used in `iFrame` to adjust the width, border, height and other stuff.

And starting in HTML5 (Only Chrome has support for this yet), you can use the `seamless` property to kinda make the iFrame part of the document, like `load()`, instead of a window inside a document.

Usually PHP is a really easy server-side language to cut-and-paste into your projects (unless if it's depend on another conflicting server-language) and you could do something like this, which would accomplish something just like `load()`:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://example.com/something.html');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

**Edit:** As Juan Mendes pointed out, you would be responsible for fetching the related JS and CSS if you used PHP (or any server-language at any rate), and that the CSS/JavaScript may not work because some selectors may depend on parent/ancestor nodes being present. With iFrames, you're just viewing the external page within your document, unlike server-language parsers, which scrape the code from the site and then print it on the page.

Comment: "PHP is a really easy server-side language to cut-and-paste into your projects" It's not that simple to use PHP if you're already using another server engine.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it on the client without JS is by putting an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe) in your div

As DumbSearch noted, you can scrape the contents on the server, use a server side DOM parsing tool (depends on your server), retrieve the content you want and paste it into your page. Note that you would be responsible for fetching the related JS and CSS, and that the CSS may not work because some selectors may depend on parent/ancestor nodes being present, just like the JS.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the stuff about the iframes and for the mention of my flaw in my answer.